# Problem with finding more

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, statistics, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I am sorrow if this question sounds silly but I really need help on this.

Question:

It takes 4 reps to complete 32 transactions. Each transaction takes 3 minutes each (180 seconds).

How many reps will it take to process these 32 transactions within 0.30 seconds?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  If a transaction takes $3$ minutes, then no transaction can be completed within $0.30$ seconds

Comment: To be clear on the question I'm asking, how many reps. will I need to complete these same transactions within 0.30 seconds as opposed to the 3 minutes with 4 reps. It's obvious I'll need more reps. but how would I calculate that?

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that multiple reps can simultaneously work on the same transaction then and their combined effort scales linearly based on the number of reps working on it?  For example, if it took one rep one minute to complete one transaction, it would take two reps 30 seconds to have completed a combined total of one transaction?

Comment: I think I might have found my own answer. Can someone check on this for me?

Since it take 4 reps to complete 32 transactions within 180 seconds, then we would need to divide an $x$ amount of reps. to get 0.30 seconds. I divided 180 seconds by 600 reps to get 0.30 seconds.

Comment: The only thing now is how do I put this into a formula instead of plugging in random numbers to get 0.30 seconds?

Comment: @JMoravitz We are assuming that these 4 reps are working on a total of 32 transactions within an hour. The average time it takes is 3 minutes (180 seconds) per session/hr. We want to know how many reps will it take to bring that 3 minutes under to a goal of 0.30 seconds?

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of my earlier comment.  With one oven, we can bake one cake in one hour.  With one oven, we can bake two cakes in two hours.  With two ovens we can bake two cakes in one hour.  Now... does that imply that with two ovens we can bake one cake in 30 minutes?

Comment: @JMoravitz ok good. So with my example, does that mean 4 reps takes 180 seconds, 8 reps takes 22.5 seconds, 12 reps takes 15 seconds, etc. Doing so we would need to divide to get a certain number of reps. I divided 180 seconds/0.3 seconds to get 600 reps. Correct me if I'm incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

So 4 reps need 
$$32*180=5760$$
seconds for 32 transactions.

Now then 8 reps would need

$$\frac{5760}{2}=2880$$
seconds.

Now solve
$$\frac{5760}{2^x}=0.3$$

which gives you 
$$x=14,22882$$

You need approximately 
$$4*2^{14.22882}=76800,06971$$
reps to complete it in 0.30 seconds.
I hope this is the correct answer.

Comment: Can you see my comments above? I think I might have found my own answer. Can someone check on this for me?

Since it take 4 reps to complete 32 transactions within 180 seconds, then we would need to divide an $x$ amount of reps. to get 0.30 seconds. I divided 180 seconds by 600 reps to get 0.30 seconds.